# Problem trying to save iterate request results

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Currently, I'm having a problem with this loop because it saves the previous result twice in each iteration.

```py
modelos_test2 = ['https://www.citibanamexchubb.com/api/chubbnet/auto/models/1/1/2020',
 'https://www.citibanamexchubb.com/api/chubbnet/auto/models/8/11/2020', 
'https://www.citibanamexchubb.com/api/chubbnet/auto/models/7/8/2020']

json_link = list()
for link in modelos_test2:
    request_link = session.get(link).json()
    json_link.append(request_link)
    print(json_link)
```

When I print json_link retrieves me a result like this

```
[{'TIPO': {'ID': '364026216', 'DESC': 'RDX'}}]
[{'TIPO': {'ID': '364026216', 'DESC': 'RDX'}}, {'TIPO': [{'ID': '382407568', 'DESC': 'NEON'}, {'ID': '382407577', 'DESC': 'PICK UP RAM'}]}]
[{'TIPO': {'ID': '364026216', 'DESC': 'RDX'}}, {'TIPO': [{'ID': '382407568', 'DESC': 'NEON'}, {'ID': '382407577', 'DESC': 'PICK UP RAM'}]}, {'TIPO': {'ID': '381390223', 'DESC': 'MINI COOPER'}}]
```

When the actual outcome should be something like this:

```
[{'TIPO': {'ID': '364026216', 'DESC': 'RDX'}}
{'TIPO': [{'ID': '382407568', 'DESC': 'NEON'}, {'ID': '382407577', 'DESC': 'PICK UP RAM'}]}
{'TIPO': {'ID': '381390223', 'DESC': 'MINI COOPER'}}]
```

Comment: you're appending it but not resetting it, causing it to add onto each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing up like that because you're printing after each iteration. Put `print(json_link)` after the loop and should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You're still appending to it, causing it to have the same thing + the new stuff. Add `json_link = list()` at the end. Like this:

```
json_link = list()
for link in modelos_test2:
    request_link = session.get(link).json()
    json_link.append(request_link)
    print(json_link)
    json_link = list()
```